# Restore managed OS disk of GCP instance using snapshot to existing VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to restore OS disk of GCP instance to existing VM, by using Snapshot taken, of OS disk, is there any API provided by Google Cloud Platform to do same.I can't find anything to help me restore a snapshot to an existing disk. Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean [this?](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restoresnapshotlargersize)

Comment: Yes @Mangu, I am talking about same, but my requirement is:
Restore the OS disk of instance, keeping the instance ID same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore a boot disk from a snapshot as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot); however, it will be given a different Instance ID. VM Instance IDs are unique to each one you create.